# Python use the print() function in a ternary conditional operator?

Tags: python, printing, boolean-logic, ternary

I don't understand why this fails

```
print('Yes') if True else print('No')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print('Yes') if True else print('No')
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

print('Yes') if True == False else print('No')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print('Yes') if True == False else print('No')
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But this does work

```
print('Yes') if True else True
Yes
```

Comment: This is python 2, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, use Python 3. :)

Comment: it works for me?

Comment: @AlexisDrakopoulos 'Cause you're using python 3, where `print` is a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because in python 2, when you write:

```
print('Yes') if True else True
```

It actually is

```
print(('Yes') if True else True)
```

So you can write :

```
print('Yes') if True else ('No')
```

Or, a bit more beautifully

```
print('Yes' if True else 'No')
```

It means that you can only use ternary operations on the "argument" of print in python2.

Answer (score 0):

The `print` function is a special statement in Python 2, so it can't be used in complex expressions line the ternary operator. Your code will work in Python 3.